# how to write text inside p:graphicImage

Tags: primefaces, jsf-1.2, jsf-2.2

I am trying to write a text inside p:graphicImage's image. I have looked at the guide of the primefaces but could not find any.

Could you please tell me how to write text inside p:graphicImage. This is my code below.

Regards
Alper Kopuz

Comment: Did you try to set "alt" of p:graphicImage ?

Comment: Do you want to alter/modifiy the contents of the image ? Or simply add an overlay text ?

Comment: I tried alt of p:graphicImage but I did not succeed at.Stephane I want to add an overlay text